# Precalculus, derivative uses.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

A ship moves with a speed of 30 km / h parallel to a straight coast. The boat is 6 km from the coast and passes a lighthouse at noon.

(a) Express the distance ($s$) between the lighthouse and the ship as a function of ($d$), the distance that has traveled the ship since noon; that is, find $f$ so that $s= f(d)$.

(b) Express $d$ as a function of $t$, the time elapsed since noon; is
say, find $g$ such that $d = g (t)$.

(c) Find ($f \circ  g$). What does this function represent?

I don't understand what does the section (a) is asking me. 
i have done the drawing to picture the scene in my head, and solved the section (b) of this excersise.

[image: This is the drwaing]

What I got from solving section (b) is:

$s= \sqrt{(30t)^2 + (6)^2}$

$s= 6\sqrt{25t^2 + 1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you wrote for $s$ answers neither (a) nor (b).

In (a) you are to write an expression for $s$ but the variable in the expression is not to be $t$, which you used, but rather $d$, which is the upper leg of the right triangle in your diagram.

In (b) you are to write an expression for $d$ (the upper leg of the right triangle in your diagram) with the variable in the expression to be $t$, the time elapsed since noon.

In (c) you are to compose those two functions (at least that seems to be what is requested, though you used the wrong symbol for function composition). You are then to state the significance of this last function expression. Hint: This is basically what you did with your expression for $s$.

Ask if you need more help to get to the final answers.

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong symbols, I'm new in this website and I haven't learn how to write them here.

Comment: By following what you just told me, the answers I got were: (a) $s=\sqrt{d^2+6^2}$ (b) $d(t)=30t$ (c) $s(t)=\sqrt{6^2+(30t)^2}=\sqrt{36+900t^2}=6\sqrt{1+25t^2}$

Comment: @VirginiaMartínHerrera: Those answers look right to me, though you did not quite answer "What does this function represent?" in part (c). I have replaced the function composition symbol in part (c) for the one you used. If that is not the correct symbol for your problem, just let me know or simply replace it yourself.

Comment: @VirginiaMartínHerrera: An excellent way to learn more about the MathJax used at this site is [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I forgot the proper MathJax way to get the centered-circle symbol and used that site to find it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes, it is the composition of two functions. The final function represents the distance between the lighthouse and the boat as the time changes. Sorry if it doesn't sound mathematical but this is not my first language haha

Answer (score 0):

$d(t)=30t$ and therefore $s(t)=\sqrt{6^2+(30t)^2}=\sqrt{36+900t^2}=6\sqrt{1+25t^2}$.

Comment: thank you very much! , but that is what section (b) is asking me and that's what i have done. What I dont understand is what section (a) is asking me because is basically the same.

Comment: @VirginiaMartínHerrera The answer to (a) is $t\mapsto30t$.

Comment: It seems to me that you gave the final answers to the problems but did not explain your reasoning--even though the reasoning is what was requested. You should add an explanation, and perhaps even remove the final answers.